# Set the console window size to match screen buffer on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

Playing around with the [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) to control the layout of a console program, and I cannot change its size.

Currently, what I can do is disable resizing, remove buttons and change the buffer size, but if I try to resize the window itself, all attempts fail; albeit, some functions do resize the window, but in pixels, so scale is drastically off.

What I've done so far (not a C++ person, just fiddling around, go easy on syntax-isms):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

COORD conBufferSize = { 150, 40 };
SMALL_RECT conScreen = { 0, 0, 150, 40 };

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX csbie;

int main()
{   
    // console opened for application
    HWND hwConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

    // hide it
    ShowWindow(hwConsole, SW_HIDE);
    
    // get the style for it
    DWORD style = GetWindowLong(hwConsole, GWL_STYLE);

    // disable maximizing and minimizing and resizing
    style &= ~(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX);
    SetWindowLong(hwConsole, GWL_STYLE, style);

    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, conBufferSize);

    // this does nothing to the window itself as best I can tell
    // if by "window" it means what portion of the display window you view "into"
    // commented out here for functionality
    // SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &conScreen);

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    
    // this sequence works, but seems by accident
    // surely there is another method?
    csbie.cbSize = sizeof(csbie);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &csbie);
    csbie.srWindow = conScreen;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &csbie);

    // required to update styles
    // using the cx/cy parameters sets size in pixels
    // that is much smaller than buffer size which accounts for font size
    // therefore this "doesn't" work
    SetWindowPos(hwConsole, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE| SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    
    // to look at the console until close
    while (1) {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now from what I can reason, if I have a screen buffer that is 100 columns by 40 rows, that doesn't translate directly to the size of the window housing the buffer. So my next thought is that I need to determine how many pixels the current console font is using, then multiply the buffer dimensions by that to determine the pixel size and use `SetWindowPos` or the `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` methods.

One thing I am unsure about is why the `srWindow` attribute is able to modify the display window with a similar description to that of `SetConsoleWindowInfo` and yet that produces no discernable change.

Answer (score 1):

> One thing I am unsure about is why the srWindow attribute is able to
> modify the display window with a similar description to that of
> SetConsoleWindowInfo and yet that produces no discernable change.

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo),

> The function fails if the specified window rectangle extends beyond
> the boundaries of the console screen buffer. This means that the Top
> and Left members of the lpConsoleWindow rectangle (or the calculated
> top and left coordinates, if bAbsolute is FALSE) cannot be less than
> zero. Similarly, the Bottom and Right members (or the calculated
> bottom and right coordinates) cannot be greater than (screen buffer
> height – 1) and (screen buffer width – 1), respectively. The function
> also fails if the Right member (or calculated right coordinate) is
> less than or equal to the Left member (or calculated left coordinate)
> or if the Bottom member (or calculated bottom coordinate) is less than
> or equal to the Top member (or calculated top coordinate).

Use [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfoex) to get the size of the screen buffer (e.p: 120,30). As long as the `SMALL_RECT` set is less than 120, 30, you will see the screen buffer size change after calling `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`.

```
SMALL_RECT conScreen = { 0, 0, 50, 20 };
...
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &conScreen);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
```

Please always check the return value of each api when debugging.